# NLog: Could not find schema information for

Tags: xsd, nlog

It seems this answer continues to evade me, and I haven't found a suitable answer on "the internets" yet.

I'm using NLog. The first few lines of my config file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
```

Sometimes when I build my VS2019 project, there are no informational messages. Other times, seemingly without changing anything, I get messages like:

- Could not find schema information for the element 'http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd:nlog'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'autoReload'.

...and so on, until it stops after 101 messages. "The maximum number of errors or warnings has been reached."

I'm in a phase now where I'm getting these messages now instead of not getting them. I've never figured this out. Why do I get them, and other times I don't? More importantly, what do I need to do to get rid of these messages for good?

When I look at the XSD in that URL, it complains about a line in the officially "published" XSD. It doesn't like connectionString, as shown in the XSD here:

```
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Name of the connection string (as specified in <connectionStrings> configuration section.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

Is their "official" XSD the problem here? I don't think that's the case, as I have another project in this solution with basically the same nlog.config, and that doesn't report any informational messages when I rebuild the solution. Just this project. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Today, after not making any changes whatsoever to my code, those messages are gone. I didn't do a full compare of the XSD between now and when I posted this. The connectionStrings part is still in their XSD, as it was before. Doesn't look like it has changed at all. What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The XSD is not valid because this is not well-formed xml:

```xml
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Name of the connection string (as specified in <connectionStrings> configuration section.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

it should be:

```xml
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Name of the connection string (as specified in &lt;connectionStrings&gt; configuration section.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

or perhaps:

```xml
<xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation><![CDATA[Name of the connection string (as specified in <connectionStrings> configuration section.]]></xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

I recommend that you fix that before looking at anything else.

Comment: Of course, except the problem is that's NLog's official XSD that I link to, not something I've created on my own.

Comment: In that case you should be asking NLog to issue a corrected version of their XSD.